# Excel formula - column changes based on result of another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

I would like to know how to change the column of a formula based on the result of another formula:

I have two columns:

| Column Letter | Transaction Count |
| --- | --- |
| A | =countif(sheet1!$A$1:$$5, "Apple") |
| B | =countif(sheet1!$B$1:$B$5, "Apple") |
| C |  |
| ... |  |
| DY |  |

As opposed to having to copying the present formula and changing the range manually, is there a formula so that I can quickly populate C to DY? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use INDIRECT.

=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE("Sheet1!$#$1:$#$5", "#", A1)), "Apple")

Comment: Hmmm I'm getting a #REF! for some reason